# Excel Web Query force XML

Tags: excel

How, in a query file, can I force Excel to process XML data as XML?

Seeing the issue using this sample file: http://www.w3schools.com/xml/plant_catalog.xml

** In Excel, click DATA then FROM WEB:

[image]

** Paste the URL above in the Address box, and once it loads click the SAVE QUERY button, and save the file somewhere local. And don't touch anything else:
[image]

** Click the IMPORT button. Excel's XML schema generator kicks in (click OK), and the data is imported as a `Table`:
[image]

** Close Excel, and double click the `.iqy` file saved earlier. The data is imported as a `NamedRange` and not a `Table`:
[image]

** The `.iqy` file is just a text file. Opening it reveals the contents:

```
WEB
1
http://www.w3schools.com/xml/plant_catalog.xml

Selection=EntirePage
Formatting=None
PreFormattedTextToColumns=True
ConsecutiveDelimitersAsOne=True
SingleBlockTextImport=False
DisableDateRecognition=False
DisableRedirections=False
```

My goal is to have an `.iqy` file that will import the data into a `Table` as if the GUI was used. In both cases Excel lists the Connection's ConnectionType as "Web Query" so I am hopeful that it can be done. Is there an option I can add to the `.iqy` file to set this?

Comment: What do you mean exactly by "treat the data as XML" ?  What is the issue ?